# A correct way to write a multivariate Gaussian measure with a covariance matrix of rank $1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution

I would like to check if I am correct about my expression.

Let $d\mu$ be a Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with mean $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and covariance matrix $B$ given by

\begin{equation}
B=\alpha \alpha^T
\end{equation}
for some fixed nonzero column vector $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Then, it is well-known that $d\mu$ is degenerate for $n>1$ and its support is given by the affine line
\begin{equation}
\bigl[ \beta + c \alpha \mid c \in \mathbb{R} \bigr] \subset \mathbb{R}^n 
\end{equation}

Now, I would like to use the parameter $c$ to express the density function of this Gaussian measure $d\mu$. Then is it correct that
\begin{equation}
d\mu\Bigl(\beta + c \alpha \Bigr)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{c^2}{2}}dc
\end{equation}
where $dc$ is just the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

I am aware that variance of $d\mu$ is $\lVert \alpha \rVert^2$, but the parameter $c$ is sort of "scaled" so that the density function seems reduced to the normal one.

Could anyone please check for me?